# Change PostGIS Column from Geometry to Geography

Tags: python, postgis, geoalchemy-2, sqlalchemy

I have a PostGIS table with a column of type `Geometry(POINT)` and SRID 0 that must be changed to the type `Geography(POINT)` as it will be used to store lat/lon values.

How can we make this alteration to the table without dropping it?

---

Table was originally created using SQLAlchemy, Geoalchemy2 and Python, with the following model defination class:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id                      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name                    = Column(String())
    coordinates             = Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

which should now be changed to

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id                      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name                    = Column(String())
    coordinates             = Column(Geography('POINT'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Pure SQL

This statement should do the job:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ALTER COLUMN your_geometry_column
 TYPE Geography(POINT, <yourFinalSRID_integer>)
USING ST_Transform(
      ST_SetSRID(
          ST_Force2D(your_geometry_column), <yourInitialSRID_integer>),
          yourFinalSRID_integer
      )::Geography(POINT);
```

You probably don't need the [`ST_Force2D`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force2D.html), but I did as my point originally was a [`POINTZ`](https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfs).

See here for an explanation:
https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html#using-geography

Documentation of the functions used:

- [ST_SetSRID](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)
- [ST_Transform](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html)

But I'm not 100% sure you need to do that, the Geometry field type can perfectly handle WGS84 values with a SRID=[4326](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html?sessionkey=3essf2xfj5) unless you have to do some [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) computations which actually requires it. Even [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) can [handle it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293310/how-to-use-geoseries-distance-to-get-the-right-answer).

#### Python

If you don't want to alter your original database, you can do the transformation of your geometries in Python as well, e.g. using [PyProj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/):

```
import pyproj
from pyproj import Transformer

import shapely.ops as sp_ops

def  transform_geom_to_srid(geom, scrs, tcrs)
    """ Transform a geometry to a new target CRS.
        Works with pyproj version >= 2.x.x
    """
    project = Transformer.from_crs(
        'EPSG:'+str(scrs),
        'EPSG:'+str(tcrs),
         always_xy=True
    )
    return sp_ops.transform(project.transform, geom)
```

Notice: if you use an older version of PyProj, you will have to set your CRS manually including an 'init=' string, e.g. `pyproj.Proj('init=EPSG:'+str(scrs))` instead of just writing the 'EPSG:' strings in the [`.from_crs()`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.2.0rel/api/transformer.html?highlight=from_crs#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_crs) method.

---

See here for PROJ documentation: https://proj.org/

And here for PyProj: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/